# How to insert a blank space in fluidRow?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a simple app as shown below. How can I modify the fluidRow statement to include a blank space between A1 and C1 so that all selectors align properly? In this instance, I do not want a 'B1' selector at all.

```
library(shiny)

inputs <- c("A0", "B0", "C0")

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(width = 2, inputs %>% map(~numericInput(.x, .x, min = 1, max = 10, value = 3))),
           column(width = 2, numericInput("A1", "A1", min = 1, max = 10, value = 3),
                  numericInput("C1", "C1", min = 1, max = 10, value = 3)))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: If you want to add an empty div, you can do something like ` column(width = 2, 
           numericInput("A1", "A1", min = 1, max = 10, value = 3),
           div(style = "height:73.5px"),
           numericInput("C1", "C1", min = 1, max = 10, value = 3)))`. But I don't like this approach. I would place inputs in a rowwise manner. I can put an example as answer if you want

Comment: This actually worked great for the actual use case (even if not the most efficient way). Thanks so much. If you put in as a full response happy to credit you with answer!

Comment: Oh thanks. I'm just adding it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this particular case, something like the following works

```r
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)

inputs <- c("A0", "B0", "C0")

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(width = 2, inputs %>% map(~numericInput(.x, .x, min = 1, max = 10, value = 3))),
           column(width = 2, 
                  numericInput("A1", "A1", min = 1, max = 10, value = 3),
                  div(style = "height:73.5px"),
                  numericInput("C1", "C1", min = 1, max = 10, value = 3))
           )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

You can modify the height of the div if you want.

However, in my opinion, a better approach is to use a row wise approach to insert the inputs. Something like the following

```r
fluidRow(
  column(2, numericInput("A0", "A0", min = 1, max = 10, value = 3)),
  column(2, numericInput("A1", "A1", min = 1, max = 10, value = 3))
),


fluidRow(
  column(2, numericInput("B0", "B0", min = 1, max = 10, value = 3))
),

fluidRow(
  column(2, numericInput("C0", "C0", min = 1, max = 10, value = 3)),
  column(2, numericInput("C1", "C1", min = 1, max = 10, value = 3))
)
```

but as you can see it is not compatible with the `map()` function as being used now.